# session variable not increment regularly

Tags: php, jquery, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I am developing a smartphone web app that is a game of question answer using jquerymobile API. 
when a user click on next button that is a anchor tag then i switch to other page and increment the $_SESSION['questionNo'] value. The problem is $_SESSION['questionNo'] value increment from 1 to 4 and then again became $_SESSION['questionNo'] is 1. why it's happening i don't know. Here is my code

```
<?php session_start();
include("connect.php");
include("header1.php");

$attemp=$_SESSION['questionNo'];
echo $attemp;
$sql = sprintf("select * from question order by pk_id ASC limit %s,%s",$attemp,1);
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$result2=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<div data-role="page" id="group">
<div class="main">
<div id="header2" class="clearfix">
<table  border="0" width="100%" id="table">

<tr><td colspan="5"><hr></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" id="menu_button1">
    <a href="reset.php" rel="external">Reset</a>
</td>

<td align="center">
    Score : 50%
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td id="menu_button2">
    <a href="test.php" rel="external">Next</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

```
-------------
test.php page
-------------
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link href="css/style.css" media="handheld, screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css"/>
    <script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">   
        <?php 
            ++$_SESSION['questionNo'];
            header('Location:startGame.php');
            exit;
        ?>      
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
```

can any one tell me why $_SESSION['questionNo'] not incrementing regularly???

Comment: Don't import jQuery twice!

Comment: <?php 
 session_start();
 ++$_SESSION['questionNo'];
 header('Location:startGame.php');
 exit;
?> I only used this code for test.php but not working it. when i refresh the page it automatically increment the value of $_SESSION['questionNo'] from 1-4 then again back to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use session_start():

```
<?php 
session_start();
++$_SESSION['questionNo'];
header('Location:startGame.php');
exit;
?>
```

Comment: i used session_start() but again value drop from 4 to 1

Comment: and if you refresh, it should be kept from 1 to 2, and etc.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: While using session_start() is important, it is also important to note that in the OP's code that portion of code should be moved to the top of the page to avoid any issues with content being sent before the headers.

Comment: I only need to increment the $_SESSION['questionNo'] value that it.

Comment: Here i got terrific problem when i refresh page it automatically increment $_SESSION['questionNo'] value from 1-4 then again back to 1.why this happening any please help me